# How can I do to do some specific filter using Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I am using Django and I woud like to do some specific filter. Let's take this example :

```
MyTable.objects.filter(number=3)
```

This query will return me all the entries which has the following criteria `number=3` but in what I would want is something like this :

```
MyTable.objects.filter(number='all')
```

And in this case I will get all the entries. I know I can do something like that :

```
MyTable.objects.all()
```

But I would like to use only filter to do that.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You do this in the view, for example:

```
mynumber = '3'  # ← can be '3', 'all', 3, 42, etc.

qs = MyTable.objects.all()
if mynumber != 'all':
    qs = qs.filter(number=mynumber)
```

so after the `if` body, if `mynumber` was `'all'`, it will take *all* the `MyTable` objects, and otherwise, it will filter the number accordingly. You thus can then continue working with `qs`.

Since querysets are *lazy*, it will *not* fetch all the `MyTable` objects from the database. As long as you do not iterate over the `qs`, or take the `len(…)`, etc. this is just a *promise* that it will perform the query.